# UIViewController.storyboard must be used from main thread only - New Error I don't know how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift

After a users authentication is confirmed, instead of transitioning to home storyboard like I tell it to it keeps crashing, why is this and how can I fix this?

```
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Pay", style: .default) { (action) in
        do {
            let context: LAContext = LAContext()
            if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
                context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Please confirm it's you") { (good, error) in
                    if good {
                        let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
                        self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
    let number = moneyTextField.text
    D_AlertController.showAlert(style: .alert, title: "Confirm", message: "Pay Robyn 
    Saunders $\(number!)?", actions: [cancelAction, confirmAction], completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```